lua cmp/lsp-config only autocompleting standard functions/structures and does not autocomplete local vaiables and functions
With my current nvim setup for lspconfig plugin:
return {

    {
        "williamboman/mason.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("mason").setup({})
        end
    },
    {
        "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
        config = function()
            require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
                    ensure_installed = { "lua_ls", "clangd" }
            })
        end
    },
    {
        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        config = function()
            local cmp_lsp = require("cmp_nvim_lsp")
            local capabilities =  vim.tbl_deep_extend(
                "force",
                {},
                vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities(),
                cmp_lsp.default_capabilities()
            )
            local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
            lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities
            })
            lspconfig.clangd.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities
            })
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, {})
            vim.keymap.set('n', 'gd', vim.lsp.buf.definition, {})
            vim.keymap.set({ 'n', 'v' }, '<space>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
        end
    }

and for completions:
return {
    {
        "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp"
    },
    {
        'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip',
        dependencies = {
            'saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip',
            "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets",
        },
    },
    {
        'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp',
        config = function()
           local cmp = require'cmp'
            require("luasnip.loaders.from_vscode").lazy_load()
            cmp.setup({
                snippet = {
                    expand = function(args)
                        require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body)
                    end,
                },
                window = {
                    completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
                    documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
                },
                mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
                    ['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
                    ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
                    ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
                    ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
                    ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }), 
                }),
                sources = cmp.config.sources({
                    { name = 'nvim-lsp' },
                    { name = 'luasnip' }, 
                    { name = 'buffer' },
                })
            }) 
        end
    }
}

The problem is that autocompletion shows snippets, does not display any errors, and works perfectly fine, apart from the fact that its not autocompleting my own defined variables and functions.
I tried checking with :LspInfo and :LspLog to see any hidden errors within them, nothing really showed up. the language servers are attached and they are working fine.

Change this line:
{ name = 'nvim-lsp' },

to
{ name = 'nvim_lsp' },


this is the second time ive had an issue where ive misread a "-" for a "_" and vice versa. thank you so fucking much
